# Search suggestion on no results to quote search terms doesn't seem right

Tags: support, search

Using the SO search, I queried:

> peertopeer javascript

I was looking for information on the new websockets standard and was met with the "Your search returned no matches" page.

The first suggestion on this page was:

> Place your search terms in quotes to search for a phrase

Now, this is obviously wrong. If you cannot find term1 + term2, how is it possible to find "term1 term2"?

Being pedantic, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow converted your search into `[javascript] peertopeer` which basically means, search for the word peertopeer in the tag javascript. This is a feature because javascript is a popular tag. Anyways, if you were to place the phrase into quotes, it would look for `peertopeer javascript` as a phrase, and questions with that phrase might not be tagged Javascript. So it's possible that there are results, but not likely.

If you want to do the `OR` search, do the following search: `"peer to peer" "javascript"`

Comment: That should read "Stack Overflow *SILENTLY* converted your search into ..." and I find that very troubeling. Doing changes from what the user asked for might be very fine, but do not do that behind the back and not inform about it.